# Fair, random voting match-up algorithm when the set of items to vote on is increasing

Tags: php, algorithm

I am creating a program where users cast a series of votes between two items chosen from a set of items.  After each vote, two new items from the set are shown and voted on, until all members of the set have been seen.

Here are my constraints:

1. Each user should see them items in a different, random order
2. The same items can be shown more than once, if necessary, but I would
   like to keep this to an absolute minimum
3. The user may vote in more than one "session", i.e. I will need to save their place and allow them to restart the voting
4. More items may have been added to the set in between a user's voting sessions

The language of choice is PHP, but I'm comfortable with algorithms given in any language, or even just pseudo-code.

Obviously this would be dead simple if only constraints 1-3 were in place.  I already have working code for that now.  What I can't figure out is how handle constraint 4 and still maintain 1 and 2.  My code for creating the array of voting match-ups, which may or may not be useful, is as follows:

```
function matchedArray($count /* # items in set*/, $seed /* rand seed for this user*/)
{
    // Make array of 1 to $count
    $input = range(1, $count);

    // Randomize the array in a repeatable way,
    // so we can save their place and come back to it later
    srand($seed);
    shuffle($input);

    // Split the array into 2 equal-size arrays
    $firsthalf = array_slice($input, 0, ceil($count / 2));
    $secondhalf = array_slice($input, ceil($count / 2));

    // If array size was odd, repeat a value in the second array
    // so that we end up with equal-sized arrays
    if ($count & 1)
    $secondhalf[] = $secondhalf[rand(0, sizeof($secondhalf) - 1)];

    // Build a two-column array using the 2 split arrays
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($firsthalf); ++$i)
    {
        $output[] = array($firsthalf[$i], $secondhalf[$i]);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

If the set has nine items, for example, the voting array would come out like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

So the first vote for this user would be between items 5 and 7, the second vote between items 2 and 3, etc.  Easy peasy, until you try adding more items into the mix after the voting has started.

Is there any way to accomplish this without losing their place **and** without having them vote on a bunch of stuff they've already seen **and** while maintaining randomness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a contradiction in requirements that will never allow a solution that everybody agrees is satisfactory. However, let me propose a solution anyways.

You need three pieces of information per session:

- the count of items at the start of the session
- the random seed used to shuffle the items
- the number of choices presented to the user during the session

When the next session starts, you need to

- recreate the `firsthalf` and `secondhalf` arrays (based on the count of items that existed at the time the session started, and the random seed)
- remove items from the two arrays (based on the number of choices made)
- combine the two arrays into one
- add the new items to the array
- you now have an array of items specific to this user, which can be shuffled, split, and presented

Note that if the user interrupts the session 10 times, then you'll need to keep 10 instances of the `{count,seed,choices}` tuple. And to get started, you'll need to `recreate,remove,combine,add` 10 times to get the arrays for the current session.